# Speeding Up Code that Simply Fills Cells with Strings

Tags: performance, excel, vba

Below is some very simple code that fills cells with strings and, along the way, prints to the statusbar to give the user some feedback. Is there anyway I can do this more quickly?

Things like screenupdating are already disabled.

My thought is to send the strings to an array and then populate the cells from an array, but I am unsure of the code that would accomplish such a task.

Let me know what I can do!

```
Sub SheetNames()

    DoEvents
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (0)"
    Range("O1") = "ASRS"
    Range("O2") = "Base Coat Line"
    Range("O3") = "Base Coat Line 2"
    Range("O4") = "Body Shop Feed"
    Range("O5") = "Cavity Wax Manual"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (5)"
    Range("O6") = "Cavity Wax Masking"
    Range("O7") = "Cavity Wax Oven"
    Range("O8") = "Cavity Wax Robots"
    Range("O9") = "Clear Coat Line 1"
    Range("O10") = "Clear Coat Line 2"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (10)"
    Range("O11") = "Control Room Robots"
    Range("O12") = "Crane 1"
    Range("O13") = "Crane 2"
    Range("O14") = "Crane 3"
    Range("O15") = "Crane 4"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (15)"
    Range("O16") = "Crane 5"
    Range("O17") = "Crane 6"
    Range("O18") = "De-Mask"
    Range("O19") = "Delivery From Assembly"
    Range("O20") = "Delivery To Assembly"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (20)"
    Range("O21") = "E-Coat"
    Range("O22") = "E-Coat Dip Process"
    Range("O23") = "E-Coat Oven"
    Range("O24") = "E-Coat Sand Strip Out"
    Range("O25") = "E-Coat Sand Strip Out Buffer"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (25)"
    Range("O26") = "Final Inspection"
    Range("O27") = "Interior Sealer 2A"
    Range("O28") = "Interior Sealer 2B"
    Range("O29") = "Interior Sealer Manual"
    Range("O30") = "Interior Sealer Robots"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (30)"
    Range("O31") = "Manual Work Decks"
    Range("O32") = "Mix Room"
    Range("O33") = "Phosphate"
    Range("O34") = "Phosphate Process"
    Range("O35") = "Polish Line"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (35)"
    Range("O36") = "Pre-Trim"
    Range("O37") = "Prim Booth"
    Range("O38") = "Prim Color Sort Buffer"
    Range("O39") = "Prime Oven"
    Range("O40") = "Prime Oven & PSO"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (40)"
    DoEvents
    Range("O41") = "Primer Automation"
    Range("O42") = "Primer Prep"
    Range("O43") = "Primer Tackoff"
    Range("O44") = "RTO 1"
    Range("O45") = "RTO 2"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (45)"
    Range("O46") = "RTO 3"
    Range("O47") = "Sealer Oven"
    Range("O48") = "Sealer Prep"
    Range("O49") = "Sealer Strip Out"
    Range("O50") = "Skid Wash"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (50)"
    Range("O51") = "Spot Repair Conveyor"
    Range("O52") = "Topcoat Blower/Feather"
    Range("O53") = "Topcoat Booth 1"
    Range("O54") = "Topcoat Booth 2"
    Range("O55") = "Topcoat Prep"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (55)"
    Range("O56") = "Topcoat Strip Out"
    Range("O57") = "UBS"
    Range("O58") = "UBS Manual"
    Range("O59") = "UBS Robots"
    Range("O60") = "VIN Scribe Robot"
    Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (60)"
    Range("O61") = "Waste Water Process"
    Application.StatusBar = "Array populated."

End Sub
```

The below is a couple answers combined, which WORKS, and is FASTER!

```
Sub FillRangeFromArray()
Dim S As Variant
Dim i As Long

S = Array("ASRS", "Base Coat Line", "Base Coat Line 2", "Body Shop Feed", "Cavity Wax Manual", _
"Cavity Wax Masking", "Cavity Wax Oven", "Cavity Wax Robots", "Clear Coat Line 1", "Clear Coat Line 2", _
"Control Room Robots", "Crane 1", "Crane 2", "Crane 3", "Crane 4", "Crane 5", "Crane 6", "De-Mask", _
"Delivery From Assembly", "Delivery To Assembly", "E-Coat", "E-Coat Dip Process", "E-Coat Oven", _
"E-Coat Sand Strip Out", "E-Coat Sand Strip Out Buffer", "Final Inspection", "Interior Sealer 2A", _
"Interior Sealer 2B", "Interior Sealer Manual", "Interior Sealer Robots", "Manual Work Decks", "Mix Room", _
"Phosphate", "Phosphate Process", "Polish Line", "Pre-Trim", "Prim Booth", "Prim Color Sort Buffer", "Prime Oven", _
"Prime Oven & PSO", "Primer Automation", "Primer Prep", "Primer Tackoff", "RTO 1", "RTO 2", "RTO 3", _
"Sealer Oven", "Sealer Prep", "Sealer Strip Out", "Skid Wash", "Spot Repair Conveyor", _
"Topcoat Blower/Feather", "Topcoat Booth 1", "Topcoat Booth 2", "Topcoat Prep", "Topcoat Strip Out", _
"UBS", "UBS Manual", "UBS Robots", "VIN Scribe Robot", "Waste Water Process")

Range("O1").Resize(UBound(S) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(S)    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't find the SO answer with these tips, but start here: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371139/how-do-i-fill-a-2-dimensional-array-with-values-and-then-put-the-results-into-a) there is an answer to a similar question, but my array will only be one dimension.

Comment: Why hard code all of those values?! Create a sheet, store the values there and copy/paste them in 1 line of code.  It would take 0 time to run and will be much easier to update and maintain.  Think about it..what if they come up with a requirement of "Add a Crane 7 option and remove Final Inspection"  That's going to be annoying and require a bit of typing.  If you have a range on a sheet, it becomes trivial to update.

Comment: This IS me filling a sheet with the values. I pull in a ton of data, then put these values to the side to reference within other code. I don't see how the way you suggest would make adaptability any better.

Comment: I think what @sous2817 is saying is to fill a sheet with these values and pull them in to the array. Which would make the adaptability MUCH better than hard coding them

Comment: That would, indeed, be better. I currently run the code from one workbook and have the data in another. I assume I would have to put the array in the macro sheet and then reference that workbook once into the data workbook?

Comment: @SilverShotBee close, but I'm saying skip the array all together and just use the sheet reference.  Just use the sheet. Hold on and I'll mock up an answer...

Comment: Okay @sous2817 - my macros are in one workbook and my data is in another. thanks

Comment: @tannman357 I see you've already accepted an answer, but I posted mine as a reference in case you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the values in one shot:

```
Dim arr
arr = Array("one", "Two", "Three")
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
```

Comment: Whilst this is simpler than my answer, I still don't understand how this "speeds up" putting 60 strings in a column... the speed of this is exactly the same as my answer, almost instant. Still, well done for further simplifying. My Personal preference is to assign the bit in the array with the value so I can easily see that `S(12)` is "Crane 1". With this way, you need to count the strings in the array. If you want to reference a single string elsewhere, you don't know what number for `S` you need to use without counting. Thats why I don't use the `Array` function

Comment: If you really want, edit your answer with this instead of the loop and I'll select your answer. Like you pointed out already, my machine is slow. I notice very subtle coding differences particularly in terms of speed. This solution is 10x faster than the loop.

Comment: Im just trying to understand why that would be though (as this site is all about expanding your knowledge after all!). So if someone can explain why this would make a difference on a machine that is limited I'd appreciate it

Comment: This is better than looping because it's building up the array in memory and then dumping it out in one pass, whereas a loop writes to each cell individually, which is slower.

Answer (score 2):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but I think this is a more flexible answer.  In the workbook where you want the headers to be, create a sheet called "Lists".  In column A of the new Lists worksheet, put in your headers starting in A2 and going down however far they need to do (feel free to put in something like "HeaderList" in A1)....this also assumes that you want the data copied to Sheet1 (you'll h ave to change to suit your situation).

```
Sub HeaderMover()
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Sheets("Lists").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Lists").Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy
    Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

So the nice thing about this bit of code and using a helper sheet comes in when you ever have to change the data.  You actually don't have to change anything but the lists column on the Lists tab.  No changes in the code need to happen.

You could do some additional checking around the last row and stuff, but my code is meant to be a guide.

Comment: This is exactly how I do lists in VBA, as it makes them flexible, even if they are in a different workbook

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SheetNames()

Dim S(61) As String


    DoEvents
    S(1) = "ASRS"
    S(2) = "Base Coat Line"
    S(3) = "Base Coat Line 2"
    S(4) = "Body Shop Feed"
    S(5) = "Cavity Wax Manual"
    S(6) = "Cavity Wax Masking"
    S(7) = "Cavity Wax Oven"
    S(8) = "Cavity Wax Robots"
    S(9) = "Clear Coat Line 1"
    S(10) = "Clear Coat Line 2"
    S(11) = "Control Room Robots"
    S(12) = "Crane 1"
    S(13) = "Crane 2"
    S(14) = "Crane 3"
    S(15) = "Crane 4"
    S(16) = "Crane 5"
    S(17) = "Crane 6"
    S(18) = "De-Mask"
    S(19) = "Delivery From Assembly"
    S(20) = "Delivery To Assembly"
    S(21) = "E-Coat"
    S(22) = "E-Coat Dip Process"
    S(23) = "E-Coat Oven"
    S(24) = "E-Coat Sand Strip Out"
    S(25) = "E-Coat Sand Strip Out Buffer"
    S(26) = "Final Inspection"
    S(27) = "Interior Sealer 2A"
    S(28) = "Interior Sealer 2B"
    S(29) = "Interior Sealer Manual"
    S(30) = "Interior Sealer Robots"
    S(31) = "Manual Work Decks"
    S(32) = "Mix Room"
    S(33) = "Phosphate"
    S(34) = "Phosphate Process"
    S(35) = "Polish Line"
    S(36) = "Pre-Trim"
    S(37) = "Prim Booth"
    S(38) = "Prim Color Sort Buffer"
    S(39) = "Prime Oven"
    S(40) = "Prime Oven & PSO"
    S(41) = "Primer Automation"
    S(42) = "Primer Prep"
    S(43) = "Primer Tackoff"
    S(44) = "RTO 1"
    S(45) = "RTO 2"
    S(46) = "RTO 3"
    S(47) = "Sealer Oven"
    S(48) = "Sealer Prep"
    S(49) = "Sealer Strip Out"
    S(50) = "Skid Wash"
    S(51) = "Spot Repair Conveyor"
    S(52) = "Topcoat Blower/Feather"
    S(53) = "Topcoat Booth 1"
    S(54) = "Topcoat Booth 2"
    S(55) = "Topcoat Prep"
    S(56) = "Topcoat Strip Out"
    S(57) = "UBS"
    S(58) = "UBS Manual"
    S(59) = "UBS Robots"
    S(60) = "VIN Scribe Robot"
    S(61) = "Waste Water Process"

For i = 1 To 61

Range("O" & i) = S(i)

Application.StatusBar = "Populating array (" & i & ")"

Next i

end sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that all at once, listing them? Instead of a line each? Thanks!

Comment: you could declare the array like `Dim S As Variant` and then
`S = Array("ASRS", "Base Coat Line", "Base Coat Line 2")` and so on so on. But it's easier to visualise and add too when presented like I have in my answer. Also the array would start at `0` this way, so using `i` wint work without using `i - 1` for every `S` occurance

Comment: Correct. I have actually done that and placed my answer below. The thing is, though, that it doesn't actually make it any FASTER.

Comment: your only putting 61 strings in a spreadsheet, if it's running slow I'd suggest it was your machine! It runs almost instantly on my machine

Comment: infact it does it in less that 1 second